# Tektro HTC 300 hydraulic fluid leakage

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I made the mistake of pulling my brake leaver whilst the wheel was off, so the piston came out, and I lost quite a bit of oil.

I pushed the piston back in, and proceeded to follow the bleed procedure for these brakes but I am having problems.

When I loosen off this bolt, about 1/4 turn, and inject the oil, all the injected oil appears to flow out of the thread shown within the red circle in the picture attached.

[image]

I've also tried sucking oil out of the top with a syringe but it doesn't seem like the system is open.

Could the loss of fluid be causing some kind of air blockage?

Could I have pushed the piston in too far,  as there is no oil behind it now.

Should I try and force oil from the top down?

I havn't got loads of oil to spare,  so I don't know what to do.

Please advise on refilling entire system, and if this is same procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: Tektro bleed instructions are usually pretty bad; can you confirm you're using a bleed block, and that when you're injecting new oil you've first opened the bleed port at the lever and attached a collection bag or bottle there? Are you sure you're opening the correct lever? Have you tried opening the caliper bleed valve a little more? Usually it wants around 1/4 to 1/2 a turn open, but that's something I've seen vary a little bit on different brakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you watch the [Tektro video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWssERgU2fw) you will see that some fluid leaks from the bottom bleed port threads as the new fluid is injected.

If *all* the fluid is leaking out, then that might indicate a blockage. You may just be getting more leakage than expected because you have to refill the entire system.

The fully retracted piston should not be blocking the system.

Comment: Managed to get it working just by pumping the fluid through.

Comment: @reggie Glad to hear you got it sorted.